# Waze Android geo URI not working

Tags: android, waze

I used to be able to start Waze navigation by using an intent with a geo URI scheme in Android. However, this no longer works. The Waze app is launched, but does not start navigation nor is there any indication that it processed the geo URI. I also tried opening a location in Waze through Facebook messenger so I know I'm not the only one facing this issue. Any idea why this no longer works or if there are any workarounds?

My code looks something like this:

```
String uriString = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "geo:0,0?q=%f,%f", latitudeInDegrees, longitudeInDegrees);

mContext.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString)));
```

I know I can use the Waze URL directly to create the Intent as explained here: https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/, but I want to let the user decide which map app to navigate with.

Thanks!